# Using jQuery in Blazor

Tags: javascript, jquery, blazor-server-side

In order to get a mobile nav menu working I've got this Javascript block:

```
function AddMobileNavMenu() {
    var $body = $('body')
    $(
        '<div id="navPanel">' +
        $('#nav').html() +
        '<a href="#navPanel" class="close"></a>' +
        '</div>'
    )
        .appendTo($body)
        .panel({
            delay: 500,
            hideOnClick: true,
            hideOnSwipe: true,
            resetScroll: true,
            resetForms: true,
            side: 'left'
        });
}
```

But I can't get that javascript working with Blazor - I've read through all the JSInterop documentation and figured out that this (in the _Host.cshtml file):

```
@page "/"
@namespace FIS2.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>FIS2</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FontAwesome/scss/fontawesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FontAwesome/scss/solid.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="FontAwesome/scss/regular.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/syncfusion/syncfusionTheme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site/Components/site.min.css" />


</head>

<body>
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/AddMobileNavMenu.js"></script>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        <environment include="Staging,Production">
            An error has occurred. This application may no longer respond until reloaded.
        </environment>
        <environment include="Development">
            An unhandled exception has occurred. See browser dev tools for details.
        </environment>
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Allows you to call it from the relevant component, like so:

```
await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("AddMobileNavMenu");
```

So long as you've injected `IJSRuntime`

The only problem is that it doesn't seem to be loading in the jQuery and triggers an error saying `appendTo is not a function`. What am I missing in order to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the issue with fresh eyes, I've realised my mistake - it turns out that it wasn't complaining about `appendTo`, but rather `panel`. I hadn't realised that was part of another library - importing that library after jquery (but before the custom function) solved the issue.

I'll leave the question here in case someone else goes down the train of thought that I did on Friday.